# How can I use CSS3 border radius and box shadow property on IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, css

I done one project using CSS3 (with the border radius and box shadow property). These properties are not working on IE. How can I use those properties on IE?

Comment: sridhar you haven't accepted any of the anwers given to questions you asked, please accept answers if you want to keep getting answers.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/downloads/detail?name=border-radius.htc

```
.my-block {
   -moz-border-radius: 10px; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* Safari, Chrome */
  -khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* KHTML */
  border-radius: 10px; /* CSS3 */
  behavior: url(border-radius.htc); /* see IE border-radius */
}
```

Comment: Ware can i use that .htc file